# Custom Class for draing Donut Charts

Tags: javascript, class, methods, scope, raphael

I am working on a project   that requires a circular user interface. The interface will be created using Raphael.js     to create rings(donut chart style) with each section being a menu item. When selected the    a new ring will be generated with the number of selections needed for the next task.

So the problem I have is creating the actual javascript class to do this. As separate   functions it works great but it's not very efficient. How do I call the new object and get the ring to show up on the screen? here is the code i am using:

```
var paper = Raphael('paper', 600, 600);
function RingObj(centerX, centerY, innerR, outerR, startAngle, endAngle, sections) {
this.centerX = centerX;
this.centerY = centerY;
this.innerR = innerR;
this.outerR = outerR;
this.startAngle = startAngle;
this.endAngle = endAngle;
this.sections = sections;

this.donutRing = function(){        
this.endAngle = 360 / this.sections;
this.endAng = this.endAngle;
paper.setStart();
for (i = 1; i <= this.sections; i++){
this.arc = function(){
radians = Math.PI / 180,
largeArc = +(this.endAngle - this.startAngle > 180);
outerX1 = this.centerX + this.outerR * Math.cos((this.startAngle-90) * radians),
outerY1 = this.centerY + this.outerR * Math.sin((this.startAngle-90) * radians),
outerX2 = this.centerX + this.outerR * Math.cos((this.endAngle-90) * radians),
outerY2 = this.centerY + this.outerR * Math.sin((this.endAngle-90) * radians),
innerX1 = this.centerX + this.innerR * Math.cos((this.endAngle-90) * radians),
innerY1 = this.centerY + this.innerR * Math.sin((this.endAngle-90) * radians),
innerX2 = this.centerX + this.innerR * Math.cos((this.startAngle-90) * radians),
innerY2 = this.centerY + this.innerR * Math.sin((this.startAngle-90) * radians);

// build the path array
this.path = [
    ["M", outerX1, outerY1], //move to the start point
    ["A", outerR, outerR, 0, largeArc, 1, outerX2, outerY2],
    ["L", innerX1, innerY1],
    ["A", innerR, innerR, 0, largeArc, 0, innerX2, innerY2],
    ["z"] //close the path
    ];                   
return this.path;

};

this.ringpath = paper.path(this.arc);
this.startAngle = this.endAngle;
this.endAngle = this.endAngle + this.endAng;
}
this.ringP = paper.setFinish();
this.ringP.attr({
          fill :'#f60',
          stroke: '#eee'
        });
return this.ringP;  
};  
};

var Ring = new RingObj (300, 300, 65, 125, 0, 45, 8);
```